# How can I make a bulma button goes full width?

Tags: css, css-frameworks, bulma

I am using [bulma@0.3.0](http://bulma.io/) css framework

I have submit button within a form as follows

```
...
<!--Submit button-->
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-full">
        <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">
            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></span>
            <span>Login</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

The result is the following

[image]

How can I make the button goes full-width ?

Comment: I think is-fullwidth is the class you are looking for

Comment: @ManuelObregozo that is correct, thank you

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Add the class `is-fullwidth`

```
<button type="submit" class="button is-primary is-fullwidth">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></span>
      <span>Login</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`is-fullwidth` did not work for me, but 
`is-overlay` did!

Comment: that sounds like a different thing.

Comment: The same happened to me. removing `is-grouped` from the parent of the `.is-fullwidth` fixed it for me.